# InvalidArgumentError: Conv2DBackpropFilter: input depth must be evenly divisible by filter depth

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD,Adam
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

train = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1 / 255, rotation_range=20,
      width_shift_range=0.2,
      height_shift_range=0.2,
      shear_range=0.2,
      zoom_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True,
      vertical_flip=True,
      fill_mode='nearest',
      brightness_range=(0.1,0.9))
validation = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1 / 255)
test = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1 / 255)

train_dataset = train.flow_from_directory('raw-img/training', target_size=(200, 200), batch_size=1,
                                          class_mode='categorical')

validation_dataset = validation.flow_from_directory('raw-img/validation', target_size=(200, 200), batch_size=1,
                                               class_mode='categorical')
test_dataset = test.flow_from_directory('raw-img/testing', target_size=(200,200), batch_size=1,
                                               class_mode='categorical')
tf.config.experimental.enable_mlir_graph_optimization()

#tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip("horizontal_and_vertical")
#tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.2)
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(200,200,3),padding='same'),
                                 
                                    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2,padding='same'),
                                    
                                    #
                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='same'),
                                     tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='same'),
                                    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2,padding='same'),
                                    #
                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='same'),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='same'),
                                    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2,padding='same'),
                                    #
                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='same'),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='same'),
                                    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2,padding='same'),
                                    #
                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='same'),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='same'),
                                    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2,padding='same'),
                                    #

                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='same'),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='same'),
                                    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2,padding='same'),
                                    #
                                    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
                                    #
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'),

                                    ])
print(model.summary())
rlronp=tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss',patience=3,verbose=1, factor=0.2)
es=tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss",patience=15,verbose=1,
                                    restore_best_weights=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=SGD(learning_rate=0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])
model_fit = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=50, batch_size=1, validation_data=validation_dataset,steps_per_epoch=len(train_dataset),validation_steps=len(validation_dataset),callbacks=[rlronp,es])
```

```
~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1181                 _r=1):
   1182               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1183               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1184               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1185                 context.async_wait()

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    887 
    888       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 889         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    890 
    891       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    948         # Lifting succeeded, so variables are initialized and we can run the
    949         # stateless function.
--> 950         return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
    951     else:
    952       _, _, _, filtered_flat_args = \

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3021       (graph_function,
   3022        filtered_flat_args) = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 3023     return graph_function._call_flat(
   3024         filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   3025 

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1958         and executing_eagerly):
   1959       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
-> 1960       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
   1961           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1962     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    589       with _InterpolateFunctionError(self):
    590         if cancellation_manager is None:
--> 591           outputs = execute.execute(
    592               str(self.signature.name),
    593               num_outputs=self._num_outputs,

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     57   try:
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError:  Conv2DBackpropFilter: input depth must be evenly divisible by filter depth
     [[{{node gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d_10/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropFilter4}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1154]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

The problem started after I installed `cuda toolkit` I tried to use the gpu but after I installed this tool I got the error.

Comment: Can you share sample data to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Comment: my dataset is : https://www.kaggle.com/alessiocorrado99/animals10